# Is there a way of identifying created Users historically on a Huawei P20 Pro?

Tags: multi-user

As there is the ability to create multiple users on a smart phone, e.g. the Huawei P20 Pro, I am curious to know if it is possible to view/keep track of all created Users on the download data of the phone? Or, is it that when a User is deleted, so is the evidence of that User ever being created on the device? Or, does the internal memory of the phone itself hold a record of all Users created?

Comment: Are you talking about "users" an Android level (multi-user system that allows to keep different sets of data for each installed app) or are you referring to the "Accounts" sections where you can add multiple user accounts from different services?

Comment: I'm referring to the created Users in Accounts e.g. Guest User, Bob, Jane, etc which you can switch between on the phone

Comment: you can install file manager like Total commander.

Go to File System Root

/mnt/user

Here you can find list of users created but it will not display usernames.

You will get to see, the date of when the user is created.

Comment: cheers - bourne.  will have a go a that.